# Custom Formatting Text with spaces at regular intervals - Excel

Tags: excel, format

I am working with a simple Excel sheet and I am trying to use custom format for text in order to put spaces at regular intervals (I do not want to add them in the cell value, but only display it in that way).

I would need the equivalent of "0000 0000 0000 0000" but that applies also to text (it does not seem to work). In my case the first two characters are not digits.

Is there some special character to do some sort of "XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX"?

Thanks a lot

Comment: In order to place that format in numbers just go for >Custom then `#### #### #### ####`. For two not numeral digits... I am afraid there is no chance in custom format, only if you add it `"AB" #### #### #### ####`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the first "AB" may vary on the various lines, and I would need to keep the info in the cell.

Comment: The issue is that as soon as you mix the numeric values with text, everything will become text.

Comment: Yep that's why I was wondering if someone had some workaround :)

Comment: You can not use *number formatting* on text data in Excel. Also, you cannot do this and retain the initial value.  If that is not an issue, and you want to overwrite your initial entry, you can use VBA with an event-triggered macro.  If preserving the initial entry is an issue, you can use a helper column and a formula.